# Plotly plots opening in non-default .html viewer when folder path contains '#'

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to plot some data in plotly and have noticed that occasionally the output plots do not open in my default .html viewer (Microsoft Edge) but open up in Internet Explorer instead. This only seems to happen when the folder I am putting the plot in contains a # character.

I am able to recreate the problem with this code:

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)

trace = [go.Scatter(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    mode='lines'
)]

fig = go.Figure(trace)
py.plot(fig, filename=r'Test\test.html')
py.plot(fig, filename=r'#Test\test.html')
```

The first plot that this outputs opens in Microsoft Edge as expected but the second opens in Internet Explorer. However when I go to the files created and reopen them from the file explorer, they both open is Edge as expected.

How can I get both of these plots to open in Edge, either programmatically or by changing my computer settings?